# CKEeditor и Equation Editor. Вставлять latex код вместо gif

Tags: angularjs, плагин, latex

Можно ли настроить плагин Equation Editor, чтобы в CKEditor добавлялся сам код latex а не формулы в виде картинок? Сторонний сервер все таки может лагать и формулы не будут отображатся

Answer (score 1):

Ckeditor 4
Решил вопрос следующим образом:
в папке `ckeditor/plugins/eqneditor/plugin.js` заменил строку

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add(pluginCmd, this.path+"dialogs/eqneditor.js");
```

на свою например

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add(pluginCmd, this.path+"dialogs/eqneditorCustom.js");
```

Это обязательно, если изменять код в самом `eqneditor.js` - ничего не происходит. Изменения видны только в своем файле с другим именем.
`В ckeditor/plugins/eqneditor/dialogs` создал этот файл `eqneditorCustom.js.`
В нем уже заменил

```
onOk : function() {
            var eqn = editor.document.createElement( 'img' );
            eqn.setAttribute( 'alt', EqEditor.getTextArea().getLaTeX());
            eqn.setAttribute( 'src', EqEditor.getTextArea().exportEquation('urlencoded'));
            editor.insertElement(eqn);
            EqEditor.Example.add_history(EqEditor.getTextArea().getLaTeX());
        }
```

На мой

```
onOk : function() {
    editor.insertHtml('<span class="math-tex">\\('+EqEditor.getTextArea().getLaTeX()+'\\)</span>');
    EqEditor.Example.add_history(EqEditor.getTextArea().getLaTeX());
}
```

Возможно в файле конфига нужно будет еще добавить

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```